# How does select * on a subquery affect performance

Tags: sql

I am writing a query that involves using several subqueries using a WITH clause.

i.e.

```
WITH z as 
 (WITH x AS 
   (SELECT col1, col2 FROM foo LEFT JOIN bar on foo.col1 = bar.col1) 
  SELECT foo, bar 
  FROM x 
  INNER JOIN table2 
  ON x.col2 = table.col2)
SELECT *
FROM z
LEFT JOIN table3
ON z.col1 = table3.col2
```

In reality, there are a few more subqueries and a lot more columns. Are there any performance issues with using the SELECT * on the subquery table (in this case, x or z)?

I want to avoid re-typing the same column names multiple times within one query but also need to optimize performance.

Comment: Try it and see?

Comment: If it's a choice between `*` or listing all the columns (i.e. `foo` and `bar` are the only columns in `x`, and you would want to select `foo` and `bar` from `z`) then there's no difference.

Comment: @melpomene right now neither way runs due to timing out. I am hoping to isolate inefficiencies that may help and this was one thought I had, knowing that a select * in general is less efficient than explicitly stating the columns, but I wasn't sure if this also applied to a subquery vs actual table.

Comment: Your query does not have any subqueries.  It does have CTEs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the database.  CTEs can be handled by:

- materializing an intermediate table and storing the results
- merging the CTE code with the rest of the query
- combining these two approaches

In the first approach, additional columns could have a small effect on performance.  In the second, there should be no effect.

That said, what usually dominates query performance is the work done for `join`s and `group by`s.  Assuming the columns are no unreasonably large, I wouldn't worry about the performance implications of using `select *` in a CTE.

I would question how you write the CTEs.  There is no need for nested CTEs, because they can be defined sequentially.

Comment: Thanks! That is helpful. So you would say that defining them like this WITH x AS (<cte1>), y AS (<cte2>), z AS (<cte3>) is better than my nested structure in the original question?

Comment: @Jasonc200 . . . Yes.  The nested structure is harder to follow and has more indentation.